# using iteration bulk import with python into sql server

Tags: python

I need to create bulk import to SQL server using python "for iteration", perhaps the code is not a complete one, but I hope you get the figure, and also if there is another way to replace "if" statements to choose the correct CSV file into a target table in SQL server

```
        import pandas
        import glob
        import os
        import datetime
        import pyodbc
        import numpy as np

        sourceCSV = [ 'AAA','BBB','CCC']
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=myDSN;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        curr = conn.cursor()

        for eachCSV in sourceCSV:
            if eachCSV=='AAA':
                targetSQLtable='dbo.targetTableAAA'
            elif eachCSV=='BBB':
                targetSQLtable='dbo.targetTableBBB'
            try:
                print("\nimport [{}] to sql".format(eachCSV))
                curr.execute("""BULK INSERT """+targetSQLtable+"""
                                    FROM 'C:\\TEMP\\Request\\"""+eachCSV+""".csv'
                                    WITH
                                    (
                                    FIRSTROW = 1,
                                    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
                                    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
                                    TABLOCK
                                    );""") 
                conn.commit()
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Not a direct solution, but personally, since you are already using pandas, I'd read the data into a dataframe `df` (assuming it is not too big). Then I'd use `df.to_sql` with `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str, fast_executemany=True)` or some such.

Comment: You can use dicts for the csv <-> tablename relation: `sourceCSV = {'AAA':'tableA', 'BBB': 'tableB'}` and access them with `for currentCSV in sourceCSV: print(currentCSV + ': ' + sourceCSV[currentCSV])`. Currently your `targetSQLtable` for CCC will be the same as it was for BBB.

Comment: thanks a lot @DerMaddi, currently i'm using your method...